# How to add all file to git repo from defined directory

Tags: git, github

I know how to add all files from current directory

```
git add .
```

How about defined directory? Something like this? Doesn't seem to work.

```
git add . ~/local-repo/
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `cd ~/local-repo && git add .`? `cp -r ~/local-repo/* ./ && git add .`?

Comment: Thought I was clear about it... Trying to accomplish adding all files from local repo to the staging area, but indirectly using a directory path without changing into directory... I think `git add ~/local-repo/.` works but not sure yet

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, you want to run `git add .` in `~/local-repo` without `cd` into it. I added an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re looking for the `-C` option:

```
git -C ~/local-repo/ add .
```

From the manpage:

```
-C <path>
   Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory.
```

It allows you to perform actions on a git repository as if you were in it.

Comment: This shorter command appears to work `git add ~/local-repo/.`

Comment: @the_prole It works only if you’re in the repository (or one of its descendents). You’d get an error otherwise: `fatal: ~/local-repo: '~/local-repo' is outside repository`.